# Command-line options working in windows, but not Linux

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, rmi

I have a `.bat` file on Windows/shell script on Linux that starts a large Java application from the command line. It configures the classpath, environment variables, etc.

At one point, it uses [RMID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/rmid.html) to configure a bunch of services which will run in their own JVMs. The problem is that it won't allow me to specify multiple JARs for the codebase property on Linux. It's allowing me to do so on Windows just fine, but I think my syntax/styling must be wrong for the `.sh` script and am hoping a more experienced Linux user could have some tip. On Windows, the working line looks like this:

```
SET RMID_OPTIONS=%RMID_VM% 
    -J-DINSTALL_DIR=%CONFIG_PATH% 
    -C-DINSTALL_DIR=%CONFIG_PATH% 
    -J-DINSTALL_DIR_LOCAL=%HOME_DIR% 
    -C-DINSTALL_DIR_LOCAL=%HOME_DIR% 
    -J-Djava.security.policy=%PL_HOME%\windows\system.policy

    -C-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=
        "file:/%HOME_DIR%\jar1.jar file:/%HOME_DIR%\jar2.jar"

    -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=
        "file:/%HOME_DIR%\jar1.jar file:/%HOME_DIR%\jar2.jar"
     // more stuff here
```

The only important lines are the ones setting the `rmi.server.codebase` property. The above works 100% fine, however, when trying to set multiple JARs in the codebase in Linux, it causes a general failure and the whole RMID command is not executed. My shell script looks like the following:

```
export RMID_OPTIONS="${RMID_VM} 
    -J-DINSTALL_DIR=${CONFIG_PATH} 
    -C-DINSTALL_DIR=${CONFIG_PATH} 
    -J-DINSTALL_DIR_LOCAL=${HOME_DIR} 
    -C-DINSTALL_DIR_LOCAL=${HOME_DIR} 
    -J-Djava.security.policy=${PL_HOME}/linux/system.policy 
    -C-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=
        ""file:/${HOME_DIR}/jar1.jar file:/${PL_HOME_LOCAL}/jar2.jar"" 
    -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=
        ""file:/${HOME_DIR}/jar1.jar file:/${PL_HOME_LOCAL}/jar2.jar"" 
     // more stuff here
     "
```

The shell script itself works perfectly fine if only one JAR is specified, but any more and I get a general failure. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? I'm open to try new things to fix this as all my attempts so far have been fruitless.

Comment: Define 'general failure'. And why the double double quotes? And why all the RMId options? You specify those when you register activatable objects, bot when you start it.

Comment: By general failure, I mean it causes the activatable objects to not register, and therefore not be able to start. The double quotes are a Linux convention to only interpret special characters when they define variables, as discussed here (http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3898896/Single-vs-Double-Quotes-in-Bash.htm). I'm not familiar enough with Linux to know if they're not appropriate in this scenario. I would be open to changing if you think it could be an issue. The specific error I'm getting is `rmid: illegal option: file://home/jar2.jar` (Sorry, I thought I put that above)

Comment: 'General' means nothing. 'Failure' means an exception or error message. You're supposed to post it here, in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux, escaping quotes is done differently. You are attempting to use the Windows specific syntax, which will result in the jar files being passed as separate arguments, instead of a single one, as it should be.

Instead of `""` to produce a quote inside quotes, you have to use `\"` in Linux:

```
export RMID_OPTIONS="... -C-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=\"file:/${HOME_DIR}/jar1.jar file:/${PL_HOME_LOCAL}/jar2.jar\" ..."
```

Aside from that, I'm not sure that the `file:/` syntax is correct. It's probably either `file://` or the absolute file path without anything preceding it, but you'll have to try it out.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. However, I've tried everything you mentioned and am still getting an Illegal Option error from RMID, specifically flagging the second jar.

Comment: How exactly do you call `rmid`? There is likely a problem there; if `RMID_OPTIONS` is left unquoted, it will still split into multiple arguments, without regard for the embedded quotes.

Comment: I'm calling it in a .sh script file after setting a bunch of environment variables dynamically. I've verified the variables are being set correctly and I've verified that the plaintext of the Linux RMID call is identical to the plaintext of the Windows RMID call, but I'm still getting the same error on Linux only.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this wrong. You don't need to start `rmid` with arguments and system properties at all. All that stuff should be specified when you register the `ActivationGroup(s)` you're going to use, in your activation setup program. That in turn means that all command-line problems should just disappear.